# Cannot run Vifm on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, windows-10, vifm

I am trying to run `Vifm` on my windows 10 x64.

I downloaded `vifm-w64-se-0.8-binary` file from sourceforge and tried to run `vifm.exe` from command prompt. This gives me the following error -

```
LINES value must be >= 2 and <= 0: got 23909
initscr(): Unable to create SP
```

I tried setting `vimcd` in `vifmrc` file and placed the file in `%USERPROFILE%`

```
set vicmd="C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe"
```

But its not working. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: When you say "from command prompt" you mean `cmd.exe` or powershell? I'd try running in the other one if one doesn't work. If you're using some console replacement (e.g. ConEmu), it might be the cause. This is actually PDCurses library failed to initialize properly, looks like it couldn't acquire console, that's why I'm thinking of some terminal emulator that messes it up (Windows is bad at this, so terminals use hacks to work). Changing configuration won't help as TUI failed to initialize.

Comment: It's the same case with `powershell`. but thank for mentioning `ConEmu`, didn't know about it.

Comment: It was a bug in Vifm, looks like they hardened argument checking for implementation of `CreateFile` compared to previous versions and I missed one of documented requirements for the call, so that it worked fine until Windows 10. Previous version should work or you can use the latest build, which I put [here](http://vifm.info/uploads/vifm-v0.8-516-gcd30ee7e3b0d-w64.exe). Thanks for implicit bug report :-)

Comment: @xaizek, thanks for the prompt fix :). It works like a charm.